# How do I use a for loop with an if statement in a kdb/Q table?

Tags: for-loop, kdb, traversal

I am new to kdb/Q. I've used Python in the past, and am trying to find out how I can traverse a kdb table using the equivalent of a for loop. I have a table called SymbolList that looks like this:

| Symbol | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2022.12.09 |  |
| Y | 2018.10.27 | 2022.12.08 |
| Z | 2018.04.04 | 2018.10.26 |
| A | 2014.10.05 | 2018.04.03 |

I am trying to take each row and plug it into a different function (already written) that spits out a boolean, and if the output of this boolean function returns True, the loop ends.

Can anyone help me with how I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your use case? Do you want to find the first row that meets some criteria? In kdb+, it's often simpler and less expensive to overcalculate and filter. So in this case you would apply your function to each row of the table and then just pick up the first instance.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you want to do with the result and what that other function does? One of the fundamental differences between q and other languages is that in q you should not be thinking in terms of loops because many of the standard operators have built-in iteration. So it is helpful to review the entire calculation from beginning to end to see whether you can rearrange operations to avoid using any loops.

Comment: Thank you @cillianreilly and PéterGyörök for your inputs. I would like to find the first row in the table that meets the criteria. My second function (that returns a boolean) is basically taking in each row and a given date, and deciding whether this given date is within the date range of each row.

Comment: So something similar in Python would be:
`for row in SymbolList:`
`    if dateWithinRange(date, row) == True:`
`        return row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your comment on what your use case is (I have also sanitised your column names - you should avoid spaces in column names):

```
q)first select from SymbolList where 2020.01.01 within(sd;ed)
sym| `Y
sd | 2018.10.27
ed | 2022.12.08
```

Replace 2020.01.01 with your given date.

If you want a tabular result instead:

```
q)select[1] from SymbolList where 2020.01.01 within(sd;ed)
sym sd         ed
-------------------------
Y   2018.10.27 2022.12.08
```

Comment: That works great, thanks for your help. What is the difference between the output in the first and second results? I checked the type for the first one and it's 99h, whereas the second is 98h

Comment: The first is a dictionary: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/dictsandtables/, the second is a table: https://code.kx.com/q/kb/faq/

Tables are just lists of dictionaries i.e. every row in a table is a dictionary in it's own right